# Theory of correlation and weighing when ensembling models

Tags: correlation, ensemble-learning

I'm ensembling models together to improve the overall performance. At the moment, I'm weighing each model by its performance under cross-validation, and this works reasonably well.

Clearly the best case for ensebling is that I have a number of well performing models which aren't well correlated with each other.

However, in reality some of my models are very closely correlated, some less well, and each has different performance.

This is problematic in cases where I have multiple strong models that are closely correlated, and one less-strong model that isn't well correlated. I can get better overall performance by dropping some of my strong models to make sure my less-strong model still has some influence.

Are their well-known methods for combining the correlation and performance measurements together to maximize overall performance?